# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{x}\cos^{3}(x)dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{x}\cos^{3}(x)dx$$

I tried to solve it by parts.I took $f(x)=\cos^{3}(x)$ so $f'(x)=-3\cos^{2}x\sin x$ and $g'(x)=e^{x}$ and I got"

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{x}\cos^{3}(x)dx=e^{x}\cos(x)+3\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{x}\cos^{2}(x)\sin(x)dx.$$

How to approach the second integral?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the facts that,

$$\cos^3x = \frac{1}{4}\left(\cos3x+3\cos x\right)$$

$$\int e^{ax}\cos(bx)dx = \frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}\left(a\cos (bx) + b\sin (bx)\right)$$

Comment: Thank you, sir!

Comment: You're most welcome!

Answer (score 5):

Use the fact that$$(\forall\theta\in\mathbb R):\cos^3(\theta)=\frac14\cos(3\theta)+\frac34\cos(\theta)$$and that therefore$$\int e^x\cos^3(x)\,\mathrm dx=\frac14\int e^x\cos(3x)\,\mathrm dx+\frac34\int e^x\cos(x)\,\mathrm dx.\tag1$$Each of the integrals of the right-hand side of $(1)$ can be computed applying integration by parts twice.

Comment: Thank you, sir!